# Extra space added to last justified inline-block element in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've come across a slight issue that appears to only occur in Chrome (tested and OK in IE10 and FF 31).

In the example provided there is `#message` and `#link`, both are set to `display: inline-block;` so that they can be vertically aligned to the middle of each other (the text in `#message` could vary in length greatly).

`text-align: justify;` has been set on `#container` to ensure that `#message` is aligned to the left and `#link` to the right.

The issue is that at certain window sizes a small "space" will appear to the right of `#link`.

**The problem:**

[image: Extra padding applied to OK button]

**What it should look like:**
[image: No extra padding applied to OK button]

**What I am actually trying to achieve:**
[image: Actual design that will be used on the site]

If you view the fiddle and can't see the problem try re-sizing the window.

1. What is causing this issue in Chrome?
2. Is there any way to fix this *without* resorting to using floats (I would like to keep vertical alignment)?

**JS Fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/vvubdqkk/**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="message">Lorem 1. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam bibendum gravida tincidunt.</div> 
    <a id="link" href="#">OK</a>
    <div id="info">Lorem 2. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam bibendum gravida tincidunt.</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 90%;
}
#message {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#link {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
}
#info {
    background-color: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is happening but using `float: right;` on `#link` does not break vertical alignment & fixes the problem!!

Comment: @ImranBughio Thanks for taking a look, unfortunately floating `#link` to the right does break vertical alignment, as it needs to be aligned to the middle of `#message` no matter how long the text is. Floating to the right pushes `#link` to the top: http://jsfiddle.net/7pj8rbh3/.

Comment: BTW when it comes to vertical alignments i always create a fake table using display: table, table-row and table-cell... & it works like a charm.

Comment: @ImranBughio Yeah, looks like I may need to go down that route, just wanted to try and understand why Chrome is having this issue as it seems to work nicely in the other browsers I have tested!

Comment: Browser compatibility often feels like wizardry specially if you have seen IE8 and below Era :p -  in this case i think chrome dealing with justify property in a different way then other browsers. Lets hope we find the problem and solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This case is a perfect candidate for using the flexbox layout. You can keep your existing code as is but add the following lines. This will keep your original code as a fallback for browsers which don't support flexbox. Since Chrome does support the current flexbox syntax [all the way back to version 21](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), this should safely eliminate your problem.

**[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/eyegray/pen/lzrFu)**

**Modified CSS**

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#message {
  flex: 1;
}
```

You'll need to vendor prefix the code for comprehensive browser support, but since you're only worried about the bug in Chrome this is not strictly necessary (unprefixed support goes back to version 29, although version 27 still holds .54% of global market share, so you might throw -webkit- in to be on the safe side).

Since flexbox can be a little confusing to use at first, if you haven't used it before there is a good overview with examples at CSS-Tricks. I don't have enough reputation points to post more than two links but just Google "css tricks flexbox".

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't really consider using flexbox due to browser support (while I want the bug fixed in Chrome I don't want other browsers to break!). Having a quick look though it seems that I may be able to setup the CSS to use flexbox if available and fall back to my current method if not.

Comment: That's the great thing about using flexbox. It will work on modern browsers but by keeping your existing CSS, it won't break on older browsers. Best of luck solving your problem.

Comment: Implemented flexbox in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j0wnhwyk/ while keeping the `display: inline-block;` fallback. Seems to work in all the browsers I have tested and has fixed the issue in Chrome. I'll probably use flexbox a bit more now that I know it can fallback gracefully. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The overall issue is you are styling #container similar to how you should instead be styling #message. #Container should simply be an imaginary holder/container of #message, #link, #info.

Try getting rid of the #container background color red and instead add it to #message. After doing that you'll encounter a few padding issues with your link (I deleted the padding:1em). Next, you can adjust the width % of #message to get the spacing right. You'll notice that I deleted width:90% on your #container.

```
#container {
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   margin: 10px 5%;
   position: fixed;
   text-align: justify;
}
#message {
    background-color: red;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 90%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#link {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
}
#info {
    background-color: green;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I like your approach although unfortunately this doesn't translate very well to my live example. I've updated my question to show what I am actually trying to achieve alongside the tailored fiddle example. The issue isn't really with the red background on `#container` it's more to do with the alignment with `#info`. The padding on `#link` is integral to the design.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the issue is caused by rounding off errors. The page seems to work i.e. there is no red gap on certain screen widths. You can test by re-sizing the window one pixel at a time. The appearance of red gap seems to be a function of container's width.

Here is my workaround:

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/vvubdqkk/46/)

It uses an extra div plus two vertical align techniques:

- The message is vertically aligned using mixed line-heights technique
- The button is vertically aligned using absolute positioning

The CSS (revised 8/26/2014):

```css
#container {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    bottom: 10px;
}
#tempwrap {
    line-height: 3; /* sets the _outer_ line height of #message as well as height of #link */
    position: relative; /* for positioning #link */
}
#message {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
    line-height: normal; /* the _inner_ line height */
    max-width: 80%; /* room for #link */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#link {
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-right: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%; /* top aligns with middle of parent */
    margin-top: -1.5em; /* the height is 3em so push 3/2em upwards */
}
#info {
    background-color: #008000;
}
```

Comment: +1. Yeah, it would appear to be a rounding issue, most annoying as the other browsers I have tested seem fine! This seems the most robust way of handling the issue. Just out of interest, is `#tempwrap:after` necessary as removing it appears to make no difference to the layout?

Comment: Regarding `#tempwrap:after`... yes, this and `min-height` both seem redundant. I was trying too many things and forgot to clean up the redundant rules.

Comment: I've removed the unnecessary rules.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Salman A I was close to flagging yours as the accepted answer but found @Isaacs solution to be a slightly preferable CSS only fix.

Answer (score 1):

[MY CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/ColoO/full/jGykB/)

For my test, i have using :

- Position absolute to fix the vertical align of #link and i fix his size
- I modified the html struture
- I modified width to compare with your picture.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="inner_top">
      <div id="message">Lorem 1. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam bibendum gravida tincidunt. Lorem 1. Aliquam bibendum gravida.nnnnn<br/><p style="color:yellow;text-align:right;margin:0">Read more</p></div> 
      <div id="link"><a  href="#">OK</a></div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
        Lorem 2. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscinngg elit. Aliquam bnbibendum       gravidda tinciduntt.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;    
    position: fixed;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
#message {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position:relative;
    max-width: 80%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top:1em;
    padding-bottom:1em;

}
#link {
    position:absolute;top:50%;right:0;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top:-25px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
#link a{
  color: #000000;
  position:relative;
  height:15px;
  display:block;
  padding-top:15px;
  text-align:center
}

#inner_top{position:relative;width: 90%; margin: 10px 5%;}

#info {

    color: #FFFFFF;   
    margin: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height:200px;
    margin: 10px 5%;
    overflow-y:auto;

}
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for taking a look. Looks like this technique is the best way to go, although I find myself gravitating to SalmanAs answer as it requires slightly less markup.

Answer (score 1):

### SIMPLE & BEST HACK - [TRY DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/1bmmdr22/2/)

**Note:** `margin = -0.5px` and `transform = 0.99px` doesn't apply any extra margin or width to your `div#container` and that also doesn't force the `a#link` to move or push the Next Pixel.

**Tested:** Chrome 36 and Safari 5.1.7

```
#link {
    -webkit-margin-start: -0.5px;
    -webkit-margin-end: -0.5px;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0.99px, 0px);
}

/* With Your CSS */
...................
```

Comment: +1. This is an interesting approach that I wouldn't have considered. While these changes seem to lessen the issue  in some circumstances I've found that it can overcompensate in others and cause `#link` to be moved too far to the right. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @HiddenHobbes Please give me one circumstance in which it can overcompensate in others and cause `#link` to be moved too far to the right.

Comment: Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bo79Ld88/. I've changed the body background to blue to make the issue more visible. If you resize the screen you will notice that at certain widths `#link` pokes outside `#container`.

Comment: I waited a bit but after testing @Isaacs flexbox method I was able to get this sorted. Thanks for your suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the these **[tricks](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)** which may help you.

Using `float : right` to your `#link` also do the trick.

Comment: OP already mentioned float is creating vertical alignment issue!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack but adding margin-right: -1px; seems to fix the issue for me:

```
#link {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1em;
    margin-right: -1px;
}
```

Problem is this will push the box right by 1 pixel in all other browsers.

Edit: Setting overflow:hidden in the container div may resolve this, though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately this isn't viable in this instance. Annoyingly it seems this space can sometimes be larger than 1px! I've also tailored the fiddle slightly for this question to make the issue easier to spot, in my live version I'm using `padding` and not `margin` on `#container` which means adding `overflow: hidden;` would not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I just might have the solution to your problem. I've been fiddling around with display: inline-block quite alot myself and now and then encountered some margin issues in both the webkit browsers, in my case, mostly Safari though. However, what usually does the trick for me is simply to set the font-size of the parent div to 0, and then *reset* the font size of the child divs to their respective original font sizes, in pixels mind you.

```
#container {
...
font-size: 0;
}

#message, #link, #info {
font-size: 16px;
}
```

Modified JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vvubdqkk/9/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately the issue is still present in your fiddle so I don't think `font-size` has much effect in this case. `margin-right: -1px;` on `#link` does reduce the problem but please see comment on the answer from Kez for why this isn't suitable in this instance.

Comment: That's wierd - I could have sworn it worked me yesterday, and in fact when checking today it still does. However it's not thanks to my solution. Instead the reason for it displaying properly on my screen spells screen resolution - on some resolutions it works like a charm and on some there'll be that tiny space on the right, try resizing your browsers window and you'll see what I mean. When resizing, the margin on the right will flicker into view, and my guess is that the reason for this is Chrome not being able to do the math properly, converting **odd** pixel values into percent.

Comment: Yeah, I think you may be right about Google calculating the percentages incorrectly, if this is the case I begin to doubt that there is a nice way of fixing the issue.

Answer (score -1):

giving margin-right to -2px will work check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vvubdqkk/30/), I have tested by resizing as well.

**CSS**

```
#link {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
color: #000000;
display: inline-block;
padding: 1em;
margin-right:-2px;
}
```

Sometime we need to do weird things in order to make things work

Comment: This answer has already been suggested by Kez, please see comments of that question to see why minus margin is unsuitable.

Comment: he suggested -1 px in which was not correct, bcoz still 1 px was showing, i suggested "-2px", I was no able to comment there as I don't have appropriate reputation to comment. thus why i chosen to answer.